# @font-face not displaying expected result

Tags: css, html, font-face

I've created a template in html and imported a text named as "abc.ttf" in css using @font-face. But its not working properly as it is displaying the default text not the one that is imported. I am using Google chrome.
further is there any simulator type tool which will let me observe my template result in different browsers.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta keyword="Qais" discription="This template is made by Muhammad Qais"/>
    <title>First template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/style.css" name="Qais" type="text/css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="body-container">
      <div id="header">
        <p>MY FONT TEST</p>
      </div>

      <div id="below-header">
        <div id="sidebar">

        </div>

        <div id="content-container">
          <div class="content-box">

          </div>

          <div class="content-box" >

          </div>
          <div class="content-box">

          </div>
          <div class="content-box">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS part:

```
  @font-face{

    font-family:"ABC";
    src:url("fonts/Body/ABC.eot?") format("eot"),
        url("fonts/Body/ABC.woff") format("woff"),
        url("fonts/Body/ABC.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("fonts/Body/ABC.svg#ABC") format("svg");
        font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;

}

    #body-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 800px;
    }

    #header {

        width:  100%;
        height: 150px;
    font-family:    ABC;
    background-color:red;
    color:      blue;
    clear:      both;
    position:   fixed;
    top:        0px;    
    z-index:    10;
    }

    #below-header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 650px;
        position: relative;
        top: 140px;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width: 25%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: purple;
        color: yellow;
        float: left;
    }

    #content-container {
        width: 75%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: yellow;
        color: blue;
        float: left;
    }

    .content-box {
        width: 25%;
        height: 235px;
        margin: 5px 10px 5px 175px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-color: rgb(0, 184, 255);
        border-top-width: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        float: left;
        box-shadow: 4px 3px 2px #888888;
    }

    #footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        clear: both;
    }
```

Directory Structure for fonts:
[image]

Comment: No information about the font itself was given. It is impossible to others to verify that the browser actually accesses the font file; you should check this using Developer Tools. If problems remain, you should provide complete but minimal code that reproduces the issue; in particular, include relevant HTML code and exclude any CSS code that does not affect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. You first **[convert your font](http://onlinefontconverter.com/font-formats)** into extension (`eot`,`woff`,`ttf`,`svg`) or another way you can download web font-face.
2. Copy your font file (extension: `eot`,`woff`,`ttf`,`svg`) to your destination path
3. Update CSS Style (base on relative font path)

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family:"ABC";
       src:url("fonts/Body/ABC.eot?") format("eot"),
           url("fonts/Body/ABC.woff") format("woff"),
           url("fonts/Body/ABC.ttf") format("truetype"),
           url("fonts/Body/ABC.svg#ABC") format("svg");
       font-weight:normal;
       font-style:normal;
   }
   ```

Now you check font face support for all web browser.

Comment: You have also need eot,woff,ttf,svg file format extension. ot you want to only for google chrome browser you should use this `url("ABC.ttf") format("truetype"),`

Comment: Now I have applied the directory structure "fonts/Body/" which contains all the fonts naming ABC.eot , ABC.ttf , ABC.svg , ABC.woff.... and replaced the css that you mentioned above but still no effect....

Comment: you have no need to set fonts/Body directory structure you just put all font-face file into fonts folder. and src url search relative path from css file to font-file file.